# How to show line numbers in Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Normally it is possible in jupyter or iPython notebooks to show lines number for a cell, however I don't see where in Google Colaboratory (Colab).

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yep, the shortcut `(Ctrl + M + L)` works,

other option is use the bar menu, at tool -> preference -> **show line numbers**

---

**Update**:
new path: Tools -> Settings -> Editor -> **show line numbers**

Comment: Accepted answer for "tool -> preference -> show line numbers". IMO this could be placed under the "view" menu.

Answer (score 8):

Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressing <kbd>M</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (one by one) switches on/off line numbers in the cells containing code.

Answer (score 2):

I see it under Tools->Settings->Editor (as on On 1//1/2020)